# Call Ajax From another Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am using jQuery to do an autocomplete on a text field. Based on the user click from that auto complete I want to call another function that does an ajax request. How can this be accomplished.Here is first autocomplete function:

```
    function lookup(inputString) {
    if(inputString.length == 0) {
        // Hide the suggestion box.
        $('#suggestions').hide();
    } else {
        $.post("ajax/autocomplete.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
            if(data.length >0) {
                $('#suggestions').show();
                $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
} // lookup

function fill(thisValue) {
    $('#inputString').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
}
```

and the second ajax call:

```
function showCar(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
document.getElementById("inputString").innerHTML="";
return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("carchoice").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax/getcar.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and the initial call to the function from the form:

```
<input type="text" size="50" value="" id="inputString" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();"/>
<div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
            <img src="images/upArrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 30px;" alt="upArrow" />
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
```

Comment: Why are you using jQuery for one AJAX call and the native XMLHTTP for the other?

Comment: umm.. I would just re-write that mess, you have jQuery .post() & then non jQuery ajax call? Looks like you just copy & pasted this without thinking it through.

Comment: I dont know? :) I only knew how to do the jQuery autocomplete based on another example and have little experience with jQuery's ajax functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call it using these lines of code:

```
$('#autoSuggestionsList').children('div').click(function () {
    showCar(this.innerHTML);
});
```

Of course in case that you're putting each result in a new div which is child to `#autoSuggestionsList`:

```
<div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">
    <div>First result</div>
    <div>Second result</div>                
</div>
```

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NaYzm/

Best regards!

Comment: I would really rewrite the javascript tho... at least make it all jQuery instead of the `showCar()` thing.